# Need help finding the sum of a series involving binomial theory

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation, computer-science, binomial-theorem

I've been stuck on this problem for 5 days trying to figure out how to simplify the sum of this series.

The series is: ${100C0}*\frac{1}{3}^{100}*6^{0} + {100C_1}*\frac{1}{3}^{101}*6^{1} + {100C_2}*\frac{1}{3}^{102}*6^{2} +...+ {100C_{100}}*\frac{1}{3}^{200}*6^{100}$

To which I noticed the series is equivalent to $$ \sum_{i=0}^{100} {100C_i}\frac{1}{3}^{100+i}*6^i $$
From here I factored out $\frac{1}{3}^{100}$ giving me $ \frac{1}{3}^{100}*\sum_{i=0}^{100} {100C_i}*\frac{1}{3}^{i}*6^i $

Next I found that $\frac{1}{3}^{i}*6^i= 2^i$. So now I have deduced that the series is = to $$ \frac{1}{3}^{100}*\sum_{i=0}^{100} {100C_i}*2^i $$

However for the life of me I have no idea what to do next and am unsure if this is even correct. I don't know how to further simplify the sum.

Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: @Buraian sorry I forgot to include them, I've corrected the mistake.

Comment: Hint: $1 = 1^2 = 1^i = 1^{100-i}$ for all integers $i$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$S= \sum_{k=0}^{100} \binom{100}{k} (\frac{1}{3})^{100+k} 6^k=\frac{1}{3^{100}} \sum_{k=0}^{100} \binom{100}{k}  2^k $$

Now, consider the binomial expansion :

$$ (1+x)^{100} = \sum_{k=0}^{100} \binom{100}{k} x^k$$

Can you finish now?

Comment: OMG IT'S THAT SIMPLE?!?! Thank you so much!!! I can't believe I didn't see this!!!

Comment: You can accept the answer by pressing the green tick mark if it helped you